# Combinatorics Question VS CS solution!

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering for some conceptual understanding to a question of this form:

In how many ways may we choose three distinct integers from [1, 2, ..., 80] so that one of them is the average of the other two?

I can solve this problem using basic computer science, but what is the correct way using combinatorics for something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

The average $A$ is uniquely determined by two other numbers, which have to have equal parity in order to $A$ be integer. So the number of ways is equal to the number of ways to choose two distinct even numbers from 1 to 80 (which is equal ${40 \choose 2}$) plus to the number of ways to choose two distinct odd numbers from 1 to 80 (which is equal ${40 \choose 2}$ again). That is, the number of ways is equal to $2{40 \choose 2}=40\cdot 39$.